# Javascript set div content to iframe

Tags: javascript, html

My script function :

```js
<script>
    function kaynakdegistir(kaynakurl) {
        $('#videoburada').innerHTML(kaynakurl);
    }
</script>
```

My on click button :

```html
<a 
    class="dropdown-item" 
    role="presentation" 
    href="#"  
    onclick='kaynakdegistir("<iframe width="100%" height="100%" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" src="https://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x7rvfqc" style="height: 400px;width: 100%;margin-top: 5px;"></iframe>");'>
    DailyMotion
</a>
```

But, it is not working and i can't find solution...

Comment: what is error message?

Comment: its not giving an error

Comment: when i see console i see this error : http://prntscr.com/ra2wkh

Comment: try to change this `href="#"` to  `href=" **location you want** "`

Comment: nope its not working :(

Comment: try this `href="https://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x7rvfqc"`

Comment: its working but i cant set embed url to all video publish services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you might be having an issue with ", You need to escape string. Replace your html code with:

```html
<a class="dropdown-item"
  role="presentation"
  href="#"
  onclick='kaynakdegistir("<iframe width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" allowfullscreen=\"\" frameborder=\"0\" src=\"https://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x7rvfqc\" style=\"height: 400px;width: 100%;margin-top: 5px;\"></iframe>");'>
DailyMotion
</a>
```